# Oddities in a C++ sorting function

Tags: c++, sorting, codeblocks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

// To Do: Finish this function
void yourFunction(int N, vector<float>&vec, float &m, float &n){
sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
n=vec[0];
m=vec[N];
}

int main()
{
    int N;
    float m,n;
    cout << "Please enter the length of array." << endl;
    cin >> N;
    float *p = (float*) malloc(sizeof(float)*N);
    cout << "Please enter the numbers in your array.";
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
        cin >> *(p+i);
    vector<float>vec(p[0],p[N-1]);
    yourFunction(N,vec,m,n);
    cout << "The largest number in your array is " << m << endl;
    cout << "The smallest number in your array is " << n << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

So this is a C++ program that is meant to identify the largest and smallest number in a user-inputted array. Code::Blocks 16, C++0X standards.
In its current state, however, when I input `1 2 3 4 5` for the array, the program's output is as following:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/phktl.png

What is the problem here? I am an amateur coder and am probably making some dumb mistakes I didn't notice. :P

Comment: Why are you using `float *p = (float*) malloc(sizeof(float)*N);`?  Just add the numbers to the vector directly using `push_back`.

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify on some parts, the first initialization to a pointer is code that is required on my assignment, I cannot edit or delete it, but I decided to use a vector instead.

Comment: In that case there is no need for a vector.  You can sort a dynamic array by passing pointers to `sort`.

Comment: Oh, that makes things a lot simpler, thanks! So would I pass *(p[0],p[N-1]) or something?

Comment: `m=vec[N];` should be N-1, but use front() and back() methods. Also you do not need to pass size, as you can get it directly from vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your biggest issue here is that

```
vector<float>vec(p[0],p[N-1]);
```

doesn't construct the vector you think it does. `p[0]` and `p[N-1]` are `floats`, not pointers.  So what you do is construct a vector with `p[0]` number of elements all with the value of `p[N-1]`.  What you need if you want to construct a `vector` for an array is

```
vector<float>vec(p,p + N);
```

---

You also have an issue with

```
m=vec[N];
```

Since `N` is the size of the vector `vec[N]` is not a valid element.  It is one past the end.  What you need is

```
m=vec[N - 1];
```

---

Do note that the vector is not needed here at all.  You can just take a `float*` in `yourFunction` and sort that directly.  That would look liked

```
void yourFunction(int N, float* data, float &m, float &n){
    std::sort(data, data + N);
    n = data[0];
    m = data[N - 1];
}

int main()
{
    int N;
    float m,n;
    cout << "Please enter the length of array." << endl;
    cin >> N;
    float *p = (float*) malloc(sizeof(float)*N);
    cout << "Please enter the numbers in your array.";
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
        cin >> *(p+i);
    yourFunction(N,p,m,n);
    cout << "The largest number in your array is " << m << endl;
    cout << "The smallest number in your array is " << n << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Even though you said you cannot change the code in `main` I would also like to let you know that `new` should be preferred over `malloc`

Comment: @NamelessKing I changed `sort` to `std::sort`.  Does that fix it?  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) is some good reading on why not to use `using namespace std;`.

Comment: Thanks a lot I should probably read up on that, just wanted to point out that in your example `vec` was not declared

Comment: @NamelessKing Oops.  Forgot to change those lines.  I just fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

First your vector creation is wrong.

```
vector<float>vec(p[0],p[N-1]);//p[0] and p[N-1] are values.You need address range

vector<float>vec(p,p+N); //begin with P(including) and end with p+N(excluding)
```

Then,

```
n=vec[0];
m=vec[N];  //Last element at N-1
}
```

should be

```
m = vec[N-1];
```

Also why do you have both array and vector.

Either use

```
std::sort(p,p+N); //and get rid of the vector
```

or directly put values into vector.

```
vector<float> vec(N);
for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
   cin>>vec[i];
```